# Sum of multiplied columns in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, select, sum

This should be easy. In MySQL I could just do:

```
select sum(column1*column2) as sum1 from table
```

How do you do this in Rails with sqlite? I've tried find_by_sql with the exact query above, as well as find(:all, :select=>...), and all sorts of other things, but none return the proper value. Most are just blank, like this:

```
[#<Element> ]
```

I could loop through, pull out values, and then sum, but it seems absurd to have to do that.

Can someone point me to what I'm obviously missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks for this, but I've been there. I can use sum on a column, but not on a multiplication of two columns.

Comment: Never mind. Element.sum( "column1*column2" ) works. Just never quite hit on the right combination of associated models and columns. Thanks!

Comment: Jed - thanks for answering your own question! Helped me from futzing even more then I have been.

Answer (score 2):

As @glortho said in a comment, the solution is

`Element.sum( "column1*column2" )`

This even works across multiple tables

`Foo.includes(:bars).references(:bars).sum('foos.cost * bars.available')`

SQL IS INCREDIBLE!